# why is my minecraft open to LAN not working 1.5.2

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When my brother and I try to play together on minecraft LAN it does not work. I have allowed all access on firewall and the direct connect trick does not work. I am on Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

It can be caused by a number of issues.

First, ensure that all clients are connected to the same router and that all users have access to your local network. This can usually be verified by logging into your router administration page; and checking that the computers are connected and running.

If that's all good; you can move on.

If when you run the LAN server, and the output from the client returns a null ip (`0.0.0.0`), it means that it cannot properly identify your NIC. This is an unfixable bug caused by your NIC. The best workaround is either opening command prompt and running 'ipconfig', finding "IPv4"' and direct connecting to that that IP address,  or creating a [full-fledged server](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Setting_up_a_server).

Answer (score 0):

Not being able to connect to a LAN network can be caused by a number of issues. First off, there is a general problem between Mac and PC's connecting, despite allowing everything through firewall. Ensure that you are all connected through your LAN (basically you can't connect to your friend from another house, unless hes using your wifi or something). Then ensure that the IP addresses are correct. I to had Windows 8 and was attempting to connect with someone and I found that I was having many issues, but since I switched back to Windows 7 it seems to work fine :/. Maybe a compatibility issue.